# Choosing men and women to groups of 7 with certain constraints

Tags: combinatorics

We have $2n$ men, $5n$ women, we want to arrange them in groups of $7$ such that there $2$ men and $5$ women in each group. There's no order in the groups or between groups. How many possibilities there are to arrange the groups?

My attempt:

The possibilities to choose men and women are: $\binom {2n} 2, \binom {5n} 5$.

The possibilities to choose groups of $7$ from the total is: $\binom {7n} 7$.

There's 'and' relationship here so we multiply to get the total of: $\binom {2n} 2 \binom {5n} 5\binom {7n} 7$

Comment: The second attempt is irrelevant with regards to the question at hand (would be relevant only if you were asked about **probability**).

Comment: Second attempt? @barakmanos

Comment: The statement in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order the men $2n!$ ways, split them in pairs and then account for the irrelevance of their order in each pair $2!^n$ ways.

Order the women $5n!$ ways, split them in fives and then account for the irrelevance of their order in each five $5!^n$ ways.

Match the pairs and fives, and then account for the irrelevance of the order of the $n$ sevens $n!$ ways.

This gives a result of  $$\dfrac{(2n)! \, (5n)! }{(2!)^n\, (5!)^n\, n!}.$$

Comment: Why there are $n$ sevens?

Comment: Are our answers equivalent?

Comment: @GinKin: there are $7n$ people in $n$ sets of seven

Comment: @barak manos: I think you may not have divided by $n!$ to take account of "There's no order in the groups or between groups".  But otherwise perhaps yes: expanding yours would lead to a lot of cancelation.

Comment: @Henry: You are correct, thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to prove that both expressions are equivalent?

Comment: One more thing, when we split the line of ordered women to fives we divide it by $5$, then divide each group of five by $5!$ to remove the order in each group and get $(5!)^n$ so shouldn't it be $5\cdot 5!^n$ in the denominator? (same with the men)

Comment: @GinKin: When you split the line of ordered women into fives you go from one set of $5n$ ordered women to $n$ ordered sets of five ordered women: this does not affect the calculation so "we divide it by 5" would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the product of the following:

- The number of ways to choose $2$ out of $2n$ men
- The number of ways to choose $5$ out of $5n$ women
- The number of ways to choose $2$ out of the remaining $2n-2$ men
- The number of ways to choose $5$ out of the remaining $5n-5$ women
- The number of ways to choose $2$ out of the remaining $2n-4$ men
- The number of ways to choose $5$ out of the remaining $5n-10$ women
- ...
- The number of ways to choose $2$ out of the remaining $2$ men
- The number of ways to choose $5$ out of the remaining $5$ women

Then, in order to cancel out identical combinations with different order, divide the result by $n!$.

---

$$\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-2k}{2}\cdot\binom{5n-5k}{5}}{n!}$$

Comment: Explanation please?

Comment: @GinKin: Kinda hard to explain in words, but you need to pick $2$ out of $2n$, then $2$ out of the remaining $2n-2$, then $2$ out of the remaining $2n-4$, ..., until you choose $2$ out of $2$. Then you need to do the same with the women, but with $5$ instead of $2$.

Comment: And with each product we have a group of 7?

Comment: @GinKin: No, but every time you choose $2$ men and $5$ women, you can join them into a group of $7$ people.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N_n$ be the number of allowed groupings where order between groups is ignored (the desired answer) and $S_n$ be the number of allowed groupings where order between groups matters. Obviously 
$N_n = \frac{S_n}{n!}$. We will calculate $S_n$ to then get $N_n$.

$S_1 = 1$ (if there are only 5 women and 2 men, only one way to form one group.
For $n>1$, you can first pick one group by choosing 2 men and 5 women, in 
$\binom{2n}{2}\binom{5n}{5}$ ways. Then you can from groups out of the remaining $7(n-1)$ people in $S_{n-1}$ ways. So the recursion relation is
$$
S_n = \binom{2n}{2}\binom{5n}{5} S_{n-1}$$

For example, 
$$S_3 = \frac{6\cdot 5}{2!} \frac{15\cdot 14\cdot 13\cdot 12 \cdot 11}{5!} S_2 =
 \frac{6\cdot 5}{2!} \frac{15\cdot 14\cdot 13\cdot 12 \cdot 11}{5!} 
 \frac{4\cdot 3}{2!} \frac{10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7 \cdot 6}{5!} S_1
$$
the pattern is clear here, and the answer becomes 
$$
S_n = \frac{\frac{(5n)!}{5!}}{(5!)^{n-1}} \frac{\frac{(2n)!}{2!}}{(2!)^{n-1}}
=\frac{(5n)!(2n)!}{(240)^n}
$$
and the answer to the problem posed is 
$$
N_n = \frac{(5n)!(2n)!}{n!(240)^n}$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(7n)!$ in the denominator in the final answer?

Comment: No, the question aks how many possibilities there are, not the likelihood of one specific possibility.